# MySql Murach's Chapter 12 - Need AS to change depending on if two columns are equal.

Tags: mysql

I am working in Murach's MySql in Chapter 12. What I need to do is this:

*Create a view named customer_addresses that shows the shipping and billing
addresses for each customer.
This view should return these columns from the Customers table: customer_id,
email_address, last_name and first_name.
This view should return these columns from the Addresses table: bill_line1,
bill_line2, bill_city, bill_state, bill_zip, ship_line1, ship_line2, ship_city, ship_state,
and ship_zip.
*The rows in this view should be sorted by the last_name and then first_name
columns.*

The Problem is all the "bill" and "ship" columns need to be created based on if the billing_address_id or shipping_address_id from the customers table match the address_id column from the addresses table. I don't have a clue on how to go about doing this. I have been playing around with if statement with no luck. Anyone have and idea on how to get this to work?

Here's what is left of my code after ripping it apart several times with no luck:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW customer_addresses
AS 
SELECT c.customer_id, email_address, last_name, 
first_name, 
IF (billing_address_id = address_id, line1, (AS ship_line1)) AS bill_line1,
IF (billing_address_id = address_id, line2, '') AS bill_line2, 
IF (billing_address_id = address_id, city, '') AS bill_city, 
IF (billing_address_id = address_id, state, '') AS bill_state, 
IF (billing_address_id = address_id, zip_code, '') AS bill_zip, 
FROM customers c JOIN addresses a
    ON c.customer_id = a.customer_id
WHERE shipping_address_id = address_id
ORDER BY last_name, first_name;
```